# Rails 3 ActiveAdmin. How to setup has_many and belongs_to with a different foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, activeadmin

So I have a shipment that can have up to three shipper companies. So I have this...

```
shipment belongs_to shipper
shipper has_many shipments
```

But I added two more columns to the shipments table: shipper_id_2 and shipper_id_3. How can I setup the association and also have ActiveAdmin realize it?

Comment: What GoodEnough proposes below is probably the right way forward.  If you want to pursue keeping the other shipper_id's in the table, you can set the foreign key that is used for matching by using the :foreign_key attribute and setting it to the column names (e.g. :foriegn_key => 'shipper_id_2 appended to your association).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a class in-between those two to assign the shipments to the shippers.

```
class ShippingAssignments
  belongs_to :shipment
  belongs_to :shipper
end

class Shipment
  has_many :shipping_assignments
  has_many :shippers, :through => :shipping_assignments
end

class Shipper
  has_many :shipping_assignments
  has_many :shipments, :through => :shipping_assignments
end
```

You can enforce the limit of 3 shippers with validators.